I can't clone the repository from Github in Pycharm
I work in linux mint in Pycharm.
When i try cloning this repository from Github Pycharm opens page with the project and closes. But folder with repository was make.
But Pycharm opened the project when I tried clone another repository.
Help me please with this trouble.
